# HeatMaps in SharePoint 2013 Wiki's

Tags: wiki, enterprise-wiki

I've used Confluence and SharePoint Wiki's in the past (Forgot what versions).  With Confluence, the Wiki Markup Language allowed me to include a heatmap at the bottom of the wiki page to show the most popular topics / links users clicked on.  Is there something similar in SharePoint 2013 Wiki WebPart?

I've done google searches, but only get 3rd party add-ons.  I'm not seeing anything native in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the wiki libraries are a library type in SharePoint the site usage and popularity trends are the only out of the box things that will help you learn out usage for your wiki pages. This isn't really a heat map but it will help you find out where people are going most often.

1. Page Ribbon > View All Pages
2. Next you can get info on a single page or see data for the entire library.

   3. **Pages:** FILES ribbon tab > (Select a page with the check mark) > Popularity Trends
   4. **Library:** LIBRARY ribbon tab > Most Popular Items

More info: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/View-Popularity-Trends-and-Most-Popular-Items-A522CC35-4E63-49DA-9968-85C588878932